# Regular expression to separate string containing upper and lower case

Tags: r, regex, strsplit

I can't get an regular expression task working, it would be great if someone could help.
I need to separate gene names from descriptions that are attached to them. Using a term that appeared in 99% of cases involved separating it from "GeneCards Summary", solvable using tidyverse via `gene <- str_split (DF$Gene, "GeneCards Summary", simplify = TRUE)`. But now there are some that do not follow this pattern, exemplified here:

```
example <- c("STAT1Predisposition to Mucocutaneous Candidiasis", 
             "PMS2DNA Repair DefectsPMS2 Deficiency", 
             "FANCACombined ImmunodeficiencyFANCA", 
             "HAX1 This gene", "ELANE ELANE is a gene", 
             "IL1RNNon-Inflammasome Related", "PRKDCT-B- SCIDDNA PKcs",
             "MSH6Severe Reduction", "AP3B1FHL Syndromes")
```

I was able to make out the following patterns, hopefully this covers all of them (unlikely but with your solution I should get the rest as well if they pop up):

1) Genename followed by a word containing UPPERCASElowerlase (So separate this part from the part before).
2) GenenameDNA (Seperate "DNA" from part before.
3) genename"" (empty space)
4) genenameT-B-.
5) genenameFHL.

Actually the trickiest is the UPPERCASe lowercase part, the others I will try to solve and post here.
Thanks a lot for your help!
Sebastian

Here is part of my solution without the upper/lower one:

```
clean_1 <- str_split(example, "DNA", simplify = T)
clean_2 <- str_split(clean_1, "[[:blank:]]", simplify = T)
clean_3 <- str_split(clean_2, "T-B", simplify = T)
clean_4 <- str_split(clean_3, "FHL", simplify = T)
```

I would do this each round to get the data cleaned up but there is probably a better way to do this.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by UPPERCASElowerlase? It is not always the case that the description starts with one uppercase followed by lowercase (for instance PMS2DNA Repair DefectsPMS2 Deficiency, which I assume you want to split between PMS2 and DNA ...). I don't really see a way how you can have a regex distinguish which uppercase letters come from the gene and which from the description.

Comment: You don't have a clear pattern to isolate the gene names in every situation. How are you getting this data? By text recognition? Extracting from other sources? Why the gene names aren't separate by space or anything else? If possible, is better to change the way data are acquired then try to correct it latter.

Comment: I get the data from a html file given out by our sequencing facility. Unfortunately there is no way to isolate them any better so I need to resort to this measure of finding irregularities before cutting them out. Not nice and clean but I guess reality rarely is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your example is representative of all possibilities, what you have is:

- The gene name is always in the beginning of the string
- It's always in uppercase, sometimes with numbers (maybe punctuations?)
- There are cases when the gene name is merged with the next sentence, that always begin with uppercase, followed by lower case.

So a solution is: extract the first word in each string, then identify the cases where there's words attached (one upper case followed by lower cases) and delete them. To keep using package stringr:

```
library(stringr)

# Extract any characters before the first space:
fWord <- str_extract(example, '([^[:blank:]]+)')

# Find the index of strings that have lower cases:
ind <- grep('[:lower:]', fWord)

# Select everything until the first lower caseand remove the last character:
fWord[ind] <- str_sub(str_extract(fWord[ind], '([^[:lower:]]+)' ), end = -2)

> fWord
[1] "STAT1"     "PMS2DNA"   "FANCA"     "HAX1"      "ELANE"     "IL1RN"    
[7] "PRKDCT-B-" "MSH6"      "AP3B1FHL"
```

I'm pretty sure that this can be done in one line. Try to make your question more clear and probably someone will present some fancy regular expression that get the job done.

Comment: Thanks a lot Carlos but not yet quite done; with this I get the last UPPERCASE letter still attached to the gene name (eg. IL1RNN instead of IL1RN or STAT1P instead of STAT1). How can I change the code so both, the UPPER and the SMALL get discharged?

Comment: That is what I commented in the answer and that Martijn had already posted in the comments: how to distinguish capital letters belonging to the gene name of which belong to the next word?

Comment: Ok, now I see what you trying to do. I'll edit the answer. Even if you accept the new solution, I strongly recommend that you edit your question to make it more clear.

Comment: I might be wrong, but POSIX character classes must be enclosed within brackets like: `grep('[[:lower:]]', fWord)`, otherwise it will match the literal characters `:`, `l`, `o`, `w`, `e`, `r`